# Drop down is not maintaining its State and showing only selected value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to select year from my drop down list and that year will be passed to my procedure in the `where` clause and will get the results. It works fine but on the view the selected value is only visible.

Example If I select 2015 from my drop down list which has 2015 and 2016 values then on the view only 2015 is visible on the drop down.
Records are perfectly fetched.

Model

```
 public class Data

{
    [Key]

    public string DataName { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Test()
    {
       VMNews objnews = new VMNews();
       if (Request["ddlYear"] != null)
        {    
            string selectedValue = Request["ddlYear"];
            objnews.DataName = db.Database.SqlQuery<Data>("usp_year @Year",new SqlParameter("@Year",selectedValue)).ToList();
        }
        Response.Write("Nothing Selected");
        return View("Index",objnews);
    }
```

View

```
 using (Html.BeginForm("Test","Home"))
{     
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlYear", new SelectList(Model.MovieName, "Year", "Year"), "ALL")
    <button type="submit">Button</button>

}
}
```

Problem is there at the view level only, I had used the HTTPPost option on the controller and on the view ForMethod.POST but it didnt worked.

Comment: Why don't you add post version of the `Test` action method?

Comment: You mean [HTTPOST] on  above action method I didit  but it didnt worked,it says server not found then I tried to use [Route(home/test)] then too it didnt worked.

Comment: Can you help me with an example.As i am sure that I am doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

If I get this straight, u want to add a listItem with more than 1 value?
In this case you should concat data into a sigle string value 
(remove public int Year { get; set; }/ add public string Year { get; set; } ) and then split it on the POST (ActionResult Test) and use them on your procedure.